# Jekyll and AngularChess

Tags: javascript, angularjs, github, jekyll, github-pages

**Problem**: I am currently using `rafeh01.github.io` to host my site. I am using `Jekyll` to update my site, post blogs, and create pages etc. I need to know how I can use things like `AngularChess` or `ChessBoardJs` to work with my website?

**Things Tried**: I have tried many things like bower install angular-chess, downloading it, and/or cloning things. I also tried creating .gitmodules files and directed them to `assets/javascripts/angular-chess`.

**Source**: I followed the application base format from here: [Jekyll Base Application Format](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/lessons/jekyll-introduction.html)

**Disclaimer**: I am NOT a developer or have experience in this. So please explain in a little bit more painful detail than you usually would. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!